# Android SwitchPreference not working correctly in 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, preferencescreen

Any idea why having multiple SwitchPreferences in a PreferenceScreen would create an issue whereby if you select any of the boxes it causes the other boxes to change? This issue occurs when testing on a Nexus 4 running 4.2.2 but not on a Galaxy S3 running 4.0.4. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/description_photo_preference">

    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="use_gallery"
            android:title="@string/title_use_gallery_preference"
            android:summaryOff="@string/summary_dont_use_gallery_as_photo_source"
            android:summaryOn="@string/summary_use_gallery_as_photo_source"
            android:defaultValue="true"
   />

    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="use_camera"
            android:title="@string/title_use_camera_preference"
            android:summaryOff="@string/summary_dont_use_camera_as_photo_source"
            android:summaryOn="@string/summary_use_camera_as_photo_source"
            android:defaultValue="true"
  />
  <SwitchPreference
            android:key="show_last_vin"
            android:title="@string/pref_string"
            android:summaryOff="@string/pref_display__false"
            android:summaryOn="@string/pref_display_true"
            android:defaultValue="true"
  />
 </PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/description_photo_quality_settings">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="prefPhotoQuality"
        android:entries="@array/photo_quality_settings"
        android:summary="@string/pref_user_photo_quality_settings"
        android:entryValues="@array/photo_quality_settings_values"
        android:title="@string/description_photo_quality_settings" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: can confirm I have faced this issue on Nexus 4.2.2

Comment: I am having the same on my Nexus 7 running 4.2.2

Comment: This is a HTC Sensation with Android 4.0.3, same issue.

Comment: Glad to see I"m not the only one facing this issue. Samsung phones seem to be working fine but Nexus and MotoX are having issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue as reported by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016168/1393002).

There is a workaround, which can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26194#c4).

Here's the workaround code:

```
public class CustomSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {

    /**
     * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
     *
     * @param context The Context that will style this preference
     * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
     * @param defStyle Theme attribute defining the default style options
     */
    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new SwitchPreference with the given style options.
     *
     * @param context The Context that will style this preference
     * @param attrs Style attributes that differ from the default
     */
    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new SwitchPreference with default style options.
     *
     * @param context The Context that will style this preference
     */
    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        // Clean listener before invoke SwitchPreference.onBindView
        ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup)view;
        clearListenerInViewGroup(viewGroup);
        super.onBindView(view);
    }

    /**
     * Clear listener in Switch for specify ViewGroup.
     *
     * @param viewGroup The ViewGroup that will need to clear the listener.
     */
    private void clearListenerInViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (null == viewGroup) {
            return;
        }

        int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for(int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
            View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(n);
            if(childView instanceof Switch) {
                final Switch switchView = (Switch) childView;
                switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                return;
            } else if (childView instanceof ViewGroup){
                ViewGroup childGroup = (ViewGroup)childView;
                clearListenerInViewGroup(childGroup);
            }
        }
    }

}
```